# jQuery change variable and apply to previously ran code

Tags: jquery, variables, onclick

I'd like to navigate through a JSON file. In order to being able to do so, I create navigational links which change the value of variable `i`. What I'm missing is how to apply the variable change on the above code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var i = 0;
  var len = 10;
  $.getJSON(file, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function (id, dat) {           
      $('div').append('<p>'+ id +'<span id="nav'+ id +'">');
      for(var j = 0; j < Object.keys(dat).length; j += len){
        $('#nav'+ id).append('<a>'+ j +'</a> ');
      }
      $('div').append('</span></p>');
      $.each(dat, function (k, d) {
       if((k >= i) && (k < i + len)) $('div').append('<span>'+d.detail)+'</span>'; //change i
      });
    });
  });

  $('div').on('click', '[id^=nav] a', function(){
    i = $(this).text();
  });   
});
```

UPDATE: this is the JSON file

```
{"5498":[{"detail":"ny"},{"detail":"qwe"},{"detail":"ghg"},{"detail":"werwe"},{"detail":"bgg"},{"detail":"qwe"},{"detail":"hgh"},{"detail":"qewq"},{"detail":"ggf"},{"detail":"vc"},{"detail":"htr"},{"detail":"htr"},{"detail":"jtyj"},{"detail":"eqw"},{"detail":"gfg"}],"46546":[{"detail":"greger"},{"detail":"jytjyt"},{"detail":"werwer"},{"detail":"jjyt"},{"detail":"greger"},{"detail":"hjtyjty"},{"detail":"fds"},{"detail":"thtr"},{"detail":"qwe"},{"detail":"htrh"},{"detail":"jyjjy"},{"detail":"ewrwe"}]}
```

The script produces such an output

```
54980 10 

nyqweghgwerwebggqwehghqewqggfvc

465460 10 

gregerjytjytwerwerjjytgregerhjtyjtyfdsthtrqwehtrh
```

I'd like to have it changed when I click on some of the links e. g. when the "10" is clicked, the output will look like this. If I click on "0", it'll look like above again.

```
54980 *10*

htrhtrjtyjeqwgfg

465460 10 

gregerjytjytwerwerjjytgregerhjtyjtyfdsthtrqwehtrh
```

Comment: Hard to tell without a standalone example with relevant JSON. You can fake the getJSON and just provide the JSON.

Comment: I added the JSON file

Comment: Is this what you expect? https://jsfiddle.net/xx2w20er/ ?

Comment: After clicking the link "10" in the navigation I expect the data below to change

Comment: What is "i" here? `$('div').on('click', '[id^=nav] a', function(){
    i = $(this).text();
  });` and where do you show it

Comment: this shows the text in the console https://jsfiddle.net/xx2w20er/1/

Comment: the i is the one declared on top and I'd like to apply its value on line 69 after after clicking the navigational link

Comment: And it is. But you do not do anything with i so you cannot see it changed - try this: https://jsfiddle.net/xx2w20er/2/

Comment: What I'd like to achive is that the 1st 2 lines in the outuput will change from  54980 10 ->nyqweghgwerwebggqwehghqewqggfvc into 54980 10 ->htrhtrjtyjeqwgfg after clicking the "10". IOW that the 2nd line contents will not be 1-10th item from the data, but 11th and onwards

Comment: But there is no code for that in your example

Comment: Right and that's what I'm asking about, how to achieve that

Comment: That was not clear until two comments ago. Please update your question with expected output, for example show before and after html

Answer (score 0):

The best solution seems to be to create an object/ array during parsing and then modify the contents

```
 $('div').on('click', '[id^=nav] a', function(){
   i = $(this).text()*1;
   for(var j = i; j < i + len; j ++) if(!(obj[id][j] === undefined || obj[id][j] === null)) $('#nav'+id).after('<span>'+obj[id][j].detail)+'</span>');
});
```